# Windows 10 Mobile crash: WinDbg shows unknown streams and unknown thread

Tags: crash, windows-runtime, windbg, windows-10-mobile

I'm not sure whether I'm debugging the crash of my WP 8.1 app properly.

#### Background

I'm investigating a crash of our Windows Phone 8.1 (RT) app when running on a Windows 10 Mobile device that occurs about once in five usages of the "finder" screen of the app. The page has a fullscreen map and we're retrieving the users location and query a SQLite table containing about 20,000 points of interest.

We're using [MetroLog](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog) which (usually) captures and logs unhandled exceptions, but in this case, nothing is logged.

#### Attempted investigation

I therefore downloaded two crash dump files from the device and tried to examine them using WinDbg. However, that produced the following warning messages:

```
WARNING: Minidump contains unknown stream type 0x15
WARNING: Minidump contains unknown stream type 0x16
WARNING: Ignoring invalid thread ID 0
```

Further, a number of errors were reported as well:

```
ERROR: Unable to find system thread FFFFFFFF
ERROR: The thread being debugged has either exited or cannot be accessed
ERROR: Many commands will not work properly
ERROR: Exception C0000194 occurred on unknown thread FFFFFFFF
(b44.ffffffff): Unknown exception - code c0000194 (first/second chance not available)
```

I've tried to use commands like `.exr -1`, `!error`, or `k` as suggested in a number of [articles](https://stephenroughley.com/2016/01/27/crash-debugging-windows-10-mobile-uwp-apps) [on the](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2014/01/13/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump/) [topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2014/05/28/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump-part-2.aspx) but they all yield more or less the same error:

```
0:???> .exr -1
WARNING: The debugger does not have a current process or thread
WARNING: Many commands will not work
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: c0000194
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0
0:???> excr
WARNING: The debugger does not have a current process or thread
WARNING: Many commands will not work
       ^ Illegal thread error in 'excr'
0:???> k
WARNING: The debugger does not have a current process or thread
WARNING: Many commands will not work
   ^ Illegal thread error in 'k'
```

#### System setup and further info

- The device in question is a Lumia 920 running Windows 10 Mobile 10.0.10586.218 (the issue itself occurs on all W10M devices, to the best of my knowledge)
- The device im investigating the crash dump is running Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.10240, due to disk space issues preventing the update and lack of time for cleanup
- I was unable to reproduce the crash with the debugger attached

#### Questions

- Is there another investigation approach I could pursue?
- What are the unknown streams 0x15 and 0x16? Should they be visible?
- Am I doing something completely wrong?

Please let me know if some infos are missing or the question could be enhanced.

Comment: c0000194 = STATUS_POSSIBLE_DEADLOCK . Can you please post the link to the store so that we can try to lauch the app?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm afraid thats not an option. The app starts just fine, its just that on some occasions, it crashes after the navigation to the maps page.

Comment: where did you get the dmp? From https://appdev.microsoft.com/storeportals? On your phone, go to Settings -> Update & Security -> For developers and set the value "Save this many crash dumps" to a vale > 0 (5 for example). After you get the app crash, connect the phone to your PC, navigate to \Documents\Debug directory and copy the dmp file to your PC. This should be a full dump and not a mini. Try to debug this dmp

Comment: @magicandre1981 this dump is from our test device already. Are there certain build/compile settings I could enable to get a better dump?

Comment: I have no idea if there is a setting to change the dump type.

Comment: Wow, I am exactly in the same situation described by you. Have you made any progress??

Comment: @Beat Sorry to hear. Sadly, we haven't made any progress.